# "Under mirror" or "Under the mirror"?

Tags: definite-article

Which one is correct?

> 1. There is a washbasin under mirror
> 2. There is a washbasin under the mirror

Comment: Related: [Where we are exactly if we're “at the sea”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115043/where-we-are-exactly-if-were-at-the-sea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only OP's second example (with the definite article ***the***) is idiomatically valid in this exact sentence.

But it *would* (just about) be possible to say ***There is an under-mirror washbasin***. That particular utterance is perhaps a *little* unusual, but [***an under-floor pipe***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22an%20under%20floor%20pipe%22) (with or without the hyphen) is a perfectly natural alternative to ***a pipe under the floor*** - where again, that second version more or less *requires* the article.

The rule of thumb is we normally include the article where it's part of an "adjectival *preposition + noun*" element that comes *after* the primary noun being modified...

> *They laid a cable **under the sea***

...but *not* when that adjectival element *precedes* the relevant noun (***cable***, in these examples)...

> *They laid an **under sea** cable*

(or ***undersea*** or ***under-sea*** - these are trivial different orthographic choices that have nothing to do with the actual *grammar* involved).